# JPanel and JScrollPane is not visible in Swing App

Tags: java, swing

I am working on a Swing Application after a long time. I might have forgotten the basics but trying to figure out why the panel and the scroll pane are not visible when I run the app. Help me out to figure out the mistakes I have done.I have a `JFrame` and a `JMenuBar` on top and then need to have a panel. Note that the `JFrame` also needs a `JScrollPane` below is my code.

```
public class FrontEndView {
private JFrame mainFrame;
private JMenuBar menubar;
private JMenu menuFile, menuEdit,menuView,menuHelp;
private JMenuItem menuItemA,menuItemB;
private JPanel mainPanel;
private JScrollPane scrollPane;
private JPanel panel1;

public FrontEndView(){
    this.prepareGUI();
}

public void prepareGUI(){
    mainFrame=new JFrame("WALL-E");
    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    int xSize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth());
    int ySize = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight());
    mainFrame.setSize(xSize,ySize);
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainFrame.setResizable(true);
    mainFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    menubar=new JMenuBar();
    menuFile=new JMenu("File");
    menuEdit=new JMenu("Edit");
    menuView=new JMenu("View");
    menuHelp=new JMenu("Help");
    menuItemA=new JMenuItem("SubMenu-A");
    menuItemB=new JMenuItem("SubMenu-B");
    menuFile.add(menuItemA);
    menuFile.add(menuItemB);

    menubar.add(menuFile);
    menubar.add(menuEdit);
    menubar.add(menuView);
    menubar.add(menuHelp);

    mainFrame.add(menubar,BorderLayout.NORTH);

    mainPanel=new JPanel();
    mainFrame.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
    scrollPane=new JScrollPane(mainPanel);


    mainFrame.add(scrollPane);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    FrontEndView  swingControlDemo = new FrontEndView();
}
}
```

Comment: Since `mainPanel` is empty (it's preferredSize will 0x0) and `JScrollPane` by default doesn't actually display scroll bars until you need them, how would you know if they were visible or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running your code, noticed that the main reason it does not showing any thing is because you didn't add any `JComponent` to your `mainPanel`. So try adding some component will show them:

```
mainPanel.add(new JLabel("I'm Visible!"));
```

Some Hints:

You should not add your `mainPanel` both to your `mainFrame` and also to your `scrollPane`. Only add your panel to the `ViewPort` region (You've already done this by passing your panel to the constructor of `JScrollPane`). Then add your `scrollPane` to your the `CENTER` of `mainFrame`.

So remove this line and it should work:

```
 mainFrame.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Also not related to the concrete problem, it is not good to add `MenuBar` to the `NORTH` of the frame. Use `JFrame#setJMenuBar` method instead.

Change this:

```
mainFrame.add(menubar,BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

To this:

```
mainFrame.setJMenuBar(menubar);
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

Scroll Pane is added by this way , with a little modification on your code.Now you can see a label on panel which is again over your mainPanel.

```
mainFrame.add(menubar,BorderLayout.NORTH);
JLabel l=new JLabel("Label on panel which is again inside scrollPane");
mainPanel=new JPanel();
//  mainFrame.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
mainPanel.add(l);
scrollPane=new JScrollPane(mainPanel);
//scrollPane.setVisible(true);
//scrollPane.setSize(10, 20);
mainFrame.add(scrollPane);
```

If you wants scroll do one more thing.

```
        scrollPane=new JScrollPane(mainPanel,
        ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
        ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
```

Comment: No need to call `setVisible` on `JScrollPane`, they are visible by default; No need to call `setSize` on `JScrollPane`, the layout manager of the frame will decide this

Comment: Thnx @MadProgrammer Got it.